# Related Field got invalid lookup: blog_posts_name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, error-handling, django-admin-filters

I am trying to add **author** to the search_field but it's throwing the error-**Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains**

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
    )
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique_for_date='publish')
author = models.ForeignKey(User,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
body = models.TextField()
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
    default='draft')

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish',
    'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body','status','author__blog_posts_name')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ('status', 'publish')
```

I have tried **search_fields =**(**'author','foreinkeyfield__author','author__name','author__User_name',)**

as per suggested by the users in the previously answered questions but none of them seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

[Django's `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) has the following fields (and others that are probably not relevant for searching by name):

- `username`
- `first_name`
- `last_name`
- `email`

You can only use existing fields in the lookups while the fields you have listed do not reference any valid DB fields.

The lookups for the above fields would look like this:

```
search_fields = (
    'author__username',
    'author__first_name',
    'author__last_name',
    'author__email',
)
```

Comment: tried but not showing the desired output..I used email address to find the post of that user but the output was not correct.